# How to identify object calls to parent functions

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to identify the calls to members of parent class by child class.
Is it possible?
For eg:

```
public class base1
{
    public void  getvalue()
    {
    }
}

public class B:base1
{
}

public class C:base1
{
}

public static void main()
{

   B objb=new B();
   C objc=new C();

   objb.getvalue();//this should display B
   objc.getvalue();//this should display C 

}
```

How can we modify getvalue() accordingly?
//Not  using Overriding concepts

Comment: The solution is to use polymorphism ("overriding").  Can you explain why you are explicitly asking for a solution "not using overriding concepts" when that is precisely what you should be doing?

Comment: I would like to know whether we can identify the child calls to parent members.Thats it

Comment: Well... _plausibly_ it could be to allow 3rd parties to implement their own subclasses and _not_ be able to cheat (have their `D` return `A`), but then you really should be checking against their Type directly not their "Name" as that can be cheated too. EDIT: Based on your comment Anjana, still not sure what you want to do; do you mean identify calls _from_ parent members, not _to_?

Comment: Yes  Mr Chris its for identifying calls from child class objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection to do this:

```
string type = objb.GetType().Name; //will be "B"
```

Comment: From my reading, the OP wants this implemented in the `getvalue` method, not at the callsite, no?

Comment: @KirkWoll From my reading, he thinks he needs the method in order to do this, which he doesn't.  In any case, you can use `GetType` in the implementation of a base class method, and it will return the actual type of the instance when run, not the type in which the method is being defined.

Comment: But how can we use the object there in the base class? What if i need to identify this "Name " from base class? i.e inside getvalue () function implementation?

Comment: @Anjana Just use it, and it will work.  It doesn't matter where it's called, it will always represent the name most-derived type of the object instance.